# Web Service without WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl2java

I have a URL that I am using with Postman that needs to contain a username and password. Also, there is 0 accompanying WSDL. However, I cannot figure out the proper way to call this inside of the java code. I have the username and password already wrote the XHTML and Java to retrieve the username and password. Can anyone give me some guidance on this process?

I have tried the following but have no luck because I would need to add a maven dependency for APOD.

```
// URL
        URL url = new URL("URL");

// Open a connection
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


        
// This line makes the request
        InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream();

// Manually converting the response body InputStream to APOD using Jackson
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        APOD apod = mapper.readValue(responseStream, APOD.class);

// Finally we have the response
        System.out.println(apod.title);
```

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: What is the endpoint url of the webservice you are trying to reach?

Comment: The URL just produces a session ID that is used to make the second web service call.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research and looking through the internet I found out the best way to do this. With the following code, I  am able to make the call without using this APOD dependency.

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("URL");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);

        int status = connection.getResponseCode();

        if(status > 299){
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                responseContent.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();
        }else{
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                responseContent.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();
        }

       result = responseContent.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I will have to manipulate the output to further retrieve a second output, however, without WSDL here is the solution.